# Navbar isn't showing links on my react app website?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, navbar

I followed a tutorial on how to display multiple pages for my reactJS program and it partially works. I have two pages: Home and Stocks, and they both have some example text in them. When I type in /home, or /stocks at the end of my localhost URL, the pages change and the correct text displays. But after having 100% identical code to the tutorial, I don't get the links on my website.

```
//index.js
ReactDOM.render(
  <Router>
    <Routes>
      <Route exact path="/home" element={<Home/>} />
      <Route exact path="/stocks" element={<Stocks/>}/>
    </Routes>
  </Router>,

  document.getElementById('root')
);

//app.js
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <NavBar />
      <Route exact path="/home" component={Home} />
      <Route exact path="/stocks" component={Stocks} />
    </div>
  );
}

//NavBar.js
function NavBar()
{
    return (
        <ul>
        <li>
            <Link to="/home">Home</Link>
        </li>
        <li>
            <Link to="/stocks">Stocks</Link>
        </li>
    </ul>
    );
}
```

There's no errors and everything works but only when I manually type in the pages. I am trying to have it so that when I type 'npm start', the home page automatically opens with links like: Home | Stocks, and then I can click whichever I want.

Answer (score 1):

```
//index.js
ReactDOM.render(
 <Router>
  <Routes>
   <Route path="/*" element={<App/>} />
  </Routes>
 </Router>,

document.getElementById('root')
);

//app.js
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <NavBar />
       <Routes>
          <Route index path="/home" component={<Home/>} />
          <Route path="/stocks" component={<Stocks/>} />
      </Routes>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Can you try like this?

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to help. This code works to an extent, it shows me the links and when I click on them, the localhost URL changes, however it doesn't display the actual .js files themselves and their contents (Home.js & Stocks.js). 
My updated imports (based on your code) in App.js is: import { Route, Routes, Link } from "react-router-dom";

Comment: Ooh sorry please change "component" keywords with "element" keyword.

Comment: Actually I just fixed the problem and now everything works. I appreciate your help, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of react router are you using? And also in your app.js file you need to fix the routes as i wrote down below.

```
//app.js
....
  <Route exact path="/home" element={<Home />} />
  <Route exact path="/stocks" element={<Stocks/>} />
...
```

Comment: "react-router-dom": "^6.4.3", and also I copied your code however the end result is still the same.

Comment: Can you try to remove "exact" parts in your code? As I remember that was on the previous versions of react-rotuter.

Comment: Yeah I took out the "exact" from all of the relevant code and the result is still the same. After "npm start", there's a blank page and I need to type /home and/or /stocks to view the respective pages.

Answer (score 0):

Change app.js and index.js alone like below,

app.js:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Router>
         <NavBar />
         <Routes>
            <Route exact path="/home" element={<Home/>} />
            <Route exact path="/stocks" element={<Stocks/>}/>
         </Routes>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}
```

index.js:

```
import { createRoot } from "react-dom/client";

import App from "./App";

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
const root = createRoot(rootElement);

root.render(
    <App />
);
```

Comment: If you are beginner to react js. Please do refer https://medium.com/@sujithsandeep/a-basic-implementation-on-react-router-dom-v6-e9ff3b4e0529